# Can I have separate settings.job for 2 instances of the same web job

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have multiple instances (one for each of my clients) of the same web job running in different app services.

The web jobs all come from the same code base which has one settings.job file in it, so each web job is triggered at the same time.

Is it possible to have one of my web jobs triggered at a different time to the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I have separate settings.job for 2 instances of the same web job

In short, it's impossible.

For scheduled WebJobs you define the schedule in the `settings.job` file. The `settings.job` file is a JSON blob that sits in the root of your WebJob project.

**When the trigger from `settings.job` is fired, the WebJob is executed and any functions you have defined can then be called to run**.

For more details, you can refer to this [article](https://keithbabinec.com/2017/06/25/azure-webjobs-scheduling-and-scaling/).